# If else on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I've this query:

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `naam` 
FROM  `klanten` 
WHERE (
`email` LIKE  '%@domain.nl%'
OR  `email2` LIKE  '%@domain.nl%'
)
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `naam` 
FROM  `klanten` 
WHERE IF(`email` > 0,
`email` LIKE  '%@domain.nl%'
,  `email2` LIKE  '%@domain.nl%'
)
```

How to check if email exist? I want to use email and if this field is empty I want to use email2. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`IF` is used to select the field, then the `LIKE` clause is placed after it:

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `naam` 
FROM  `klanten` 
WHERE IF(`email` != '', `email`, `email2`) LIKE  '%@domain.nl%'
```

Comment: On second tought I like your answer the best

Comment: Can I use IF to filter out more fields? I want to do `if (active = 1) AND startDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. Is something like that possible?

Comment: @TomHart: `IF` here is just used to select one field vs the other.  It makes no sense in your example.  Do you mean: `WHERE active=1 AND startDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: Not exactly, I only want it to check the start date if active is 1.

Comment: @TomHart: `WHERE active=1 AND startDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.  I'm pretty sure MySQL will short circuit and stop evaluating if `active` isn't 1.

Comment: So if I have the startDate criteria at the very end of the WHERE, it should work as intended? (I don't have access to check this at the moment)

Comment: @TomHart: I think so.  I'm not 100% sure that MySQL does short circuit evaluation.  You can also try `WHERE IF(active = 1, startDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)` (or whatever you want to happen if `active` is not 1).

Comment: I'll look at the IF syntax now, basically if active is 0 (it's only either 1 or 0) it ignores the start date.

Comment: @TomHart: Are there more criteria after that?  You can also try `WHERE CASE WHEN active=1 THEN startDate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() END`.  That might be better here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57761/discussion-between-tom-hart-and-rocket-hazmat).

Comment: Is that room available on chat.stachexchange? chat.stackoverflow is blocked at my work.

Comment: @TomHart: It should be, but I don't have time to join a chat right now.

Comment: Okay not a problem, I have a working solution at the moment, but I'll look as using CASE instead as it seems more elegant. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: This works on HeidiSql but SpringData nativeQuery. Do you know why?

Comment: @menoktaokan What's the issue you're seeing?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It was like Spring Data didn't recognize the syntax so I changed the path.

Comment: I did it with a `BETWEEN` and it also worked, apparently the `IF` validates which column will be filtered. `WHERE IF (ca.schedule_date != '', DATE(ca.schedule_date), DATE(ca.date_created)) BETWEEN '2022-08-12' AND '2022-08-12'`;

Answer (score 18):

You want to use `coalesce()`:

```
where coalesce(email, email2) like '%anja@fiskkoer.nl%'
```

If you want to handle *empty* strings ('') versus NULL, a case works:

```
where (case when email is NULL or email = '' then email2 else email end) like '%anja@fiskkoer.nl%'
```

And, if you are worried about the string really being just spaces:

```
where (case when email is NULL or ltrim(email) = '' then email2 else email end) like '%anja@fiskkoer.nl%'
```

As an aside, the sample `if` statement is really saying "If email starts with a number larger than 0".  This is because the comparison is to 0, a number.  MySQL implicitly tries to convert the string to a number.  So, 'abcd@de.com' would fail, because the string would convert as 0.  As would '0abc@de.com'.  But, '1abc@de.com' and '01abc@de.com' would succeed.

Comment: @mtahmed No it won't - I've noted that in my answer. The question is not clear on what would be the correct check.

Comment: @mtahmed no, `COALESCE` will only work on `NULL`. But columns: email, email2 are nullable right?

Comment: The field or the table cell if you like is just '' and not NULL so there you go. ps, the database itself is not made by me!

Answer (score 3):

Note the following is functionally different to Gordon Linoff's answer. His answer assumes that you want to use `email2` if `email` is NULL. Mine assumes you  want to use `email2` if `email` is an empty-string. The correct answer will depend on your database (or you could perform a NULL check *and* an empty-string check - it all depends on what is appropriate for your database design).

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `naam` 
FROM  `klanten` 
WHERE `email` LIKE  '%anja@fiskkoer.nl%'
OR (LENGTH(email) = 0 AND `email2` LIKE  '%anja@fiskkoer.nl%')
```

Comment: Actually, does `email IS ''` work instead of `LENGTH(email) = 0`?

Comment: this works for me thank you for you answer. Note that I look for the domain and not the email itself. That is why I use LIKE %%.

Comment: @mtahmed Yes, that does work. I was just copying the question as closely as possible, so my answer would be more understandable to the author (although it would be `email = ''` surely?)

Comment: The reason I am asking was because when checking for empty string, it's almost always better to do string compare (`email = ''`) instead of checking length (`LENGTH(email) = 0`) because it's faster to do string compare.

Comment: @mtahmed . . . Do you have a reference on why the string compare is faster than the length?  Given that the length is stored prior to any data in the string, I would expect a length comparison to possibly be faster.  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html)

Comment: Oh I meant it as a general comment: I use string compare whenever I can. Also, it's a one byte compare for string compare while it's 4 or 8 byte compare for length compare (comparing char vs integer).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample query for a table having a foreign key relationship to the same table with a query parameter.

[image]

```sql
SET @x = -1;
SELECT id, categoryName 
FROM Catergory WHERE IF(@x > 0,category_ParentId = @x,category_ParentId IS NOT NULL);
```

`@x` can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

try this ,hope it helps

```
select user_display_image as user_image,
user_display_name as user_name,
invitee_phone,
(
 CASE 
    WHEN invitee_status=1 THEN "attending" 
    WHEN invitee_status=2 THEN "unsure" 
    WHEN invitee_status=3 THEN "declined" 
    WHEN invitee_status=0 THEN "notreviwed" END
) AS  invitee_status
 FROM your_tbl
```