# PG::Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, integer

I'm making a search-function in a Rails project with Postgres as db.

Here's my code

```
def self.search(search)
   if search 
    find(:all, :conditions => ["LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(address) LIKE LOWER(?) OR (venue_type) LIKE (?)", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

But my problem is that "venue_type" is an integer. I've made a case switch for venue_type

```
def venue_type_check
    case self.venue_type
      when 1
        "Pub"
      when 2
        "Nattklubb"
    end
end
```

Now to my question: How can I find something in my query when venue_type is an int?

Comment: Please try with: find(:all, :conditions => ["LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(address) LIKE LOWER(?) OR (venue_type = ?)", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", search.to_i])

Comment: Where is the error `PG::Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown` being thrown?

Comment: @BachanSmruty I tried your way, but when I search for "Nattklubb" (venue_type), I don't get any results. :/

Comment: @rsvmrk, Please check my answer. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. Here I have added switch case to where clause.

```
def self.search(search)
           if search 
            find(:all, :conditions => ["LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(address) LIKE LOWER(?) OR (venue_type = CASE WHEN 'pub' = ? THEN 1 WHEN 'nattklubb' = ? THEN 2 END)", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "#{search.downcase}", "#{search.downcase}"])
            else
              find(:all)
            end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I tried your code, but for some reason I get this error:

PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...ub' = '%white%' THEN 1 WHEN 'Nattklubb' = '%white%' THEN 2))


                                                                    ^
: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues"  WHERE (LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%white%') OR LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER('%white%') OR LOWER(address) LIKE LOWER('%white%') OR (venue_type = CASE WHEN 'Pub' = '%white%' THEN 1 WHEN 'Nattklubb' = '%white%' THEN 2))

Comment: @rsvmrk, sorry, I missed the END in the switch case. I have modified it. Please check it now

Comment: I don't know if my comment made any sense now, sorry for that.

Comment: No no.. thanks for your comment otherwise how could I know that, there is some error in my answer.. thanks for the comment.. :)

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works out kind of... The funny part is: when I search for 1 or 2, then "Nattklubb" or "Pub" appears. How can I reverse this?

Comment: I have modified the query, have a try with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [`if-else condition in your where clause`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162404/if-else-on-where-clause) something like following

```
find(:all, :conditions => ["LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(?) OR LOWER(city) LIKE LOWER(?)
            OR LOWER(address) LIKE LOWER(?) OR    
    IF(venue_type == 1, 'Pub', IF(venue_type == 2, 'Nattklubb2',  '')) LIKE (?)", 
                 "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 3.2 or greater, you should use `where( [] )` instead for `find`.

```
where( [ "field like ?", field ] ).order(). ...
```

Also, when using pgsql why are you not using `ilike` instead of `like` with `lower`?

In your case while searching int or not int, I would use different queries.

When `search.to_i != 0`