# MySql query result for each condition

Tags: mysql

In following query, is there any possibility to having different results for different conditions?

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ((COND1) || (COND2) || (COND3 AND COND4) || COND5);
```

I mean if search token stoped at a record for COND2 then result having some number or anything that we want. some thing like this:

I need something like this

```
SELECT someVar FROM `table` WHERE ((COND1 then someVar=5)...
```

that results something like this:

```
╔═════════╗
║ someVar ║
╠═════════╣
║    5    ║
╠═════════╣
║    6    ║
╠═════════╣
║    19   ║
╚═════════╝
```

*In my case I want to search duplicates in some specific cases so I'm giving a bunch of ids and duplicate conditions to a query, and I need that query returns me which id has a dupicate, it returns me which id is duplicate by given id. sorry for my bad english*

this is my query:

```
SELECT `bId` FROM `betmatches` WHERE `user`='1' AND `status`='paid' AND ((`zpo`='zpo2' AND `mId`='2355') OR (`zpo`='zpo2' AND `mId`='2367'))
```

if following condition was true

```
(`zpo`='zpo2' AND `mId`='2355')
```

i need query to result me some number like `5`

Comment: I think you are looking for UNION SELECT

Comment: what is that @bub ?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162404/if-else-on-where-clause)?

Comment: @Omid google will tell you what it is ;)

Comment: @bub it's not union i think

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the following?

```
Select name FROM foo WHERE zip_code=76110 OR state='TX' or a=1 AND b=1
```

Make sure you understand ORs, ANDs, and XORs.

Comment: I didn't mean that, i want to search duplicates in some specific case so i'm giving a bunch of ids and duplicate conditions to a query, and I need that uery returns me which id has a dupicate, it returns me which id is duplicate by given id. sorry for my bad english